# Fancy box, grab from url

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I was developing a site and am using bootstrap, and jquery... I found out that bootstrap has modals that is exactly like fancybox, but realized it was not good enough, so I went ahead and got fancybox... I recently saw a website called PrimeDice, and I saw that they were also using fancybox, and I want to setup fancybox, like they did... If you look into their code, you can see that they are getting the fancybox like this...

```
<a href="/modals/faq.html" class="action-fancybox">faq</a>
```

Basically what is happening is that if you go to http://primedice.com/modals/faq.html you will see the plain text version of the fancy box. I want to do something similar to this, where it fetches the text or data of the fancybox from a different page... So basically have a folder called modals, and have a file called text.php and then fetch the information from that, and display it as a fancybox on my homepage... I hope you understand what I mean...

This is what their faq code looks like: http://pastie.org/8345073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this html

```
<a href="/modals/faq.html" class="action-fancybox">faq</a>
```

then use a jQuery code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".action-fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe"
    });
});
```

Assuming that you have properly loaded jQuery as well as fancybox js and css files.

See it working in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TZzLu/)**

Comment: Quick question... This is how PrimeDice's page looks http://puu.sh/4x1Em.png and this is how your page looks http://puu.sh/4x1FE.png How would I be able to get somewhat close styling? Like the header and stuff? The faq page that is loaded from the modals folder, has styling in it, but it is not loading... I hope you understand!

Comment: if you are loading the external page from within your own domain, the use `ajax` instead of `iframe` and the page will use any style you loaded in your main page.

Comment: Almost there! The modal works when I use iframe on a page that is on my local domain, but when I change type: "iframe" to type: "ajax", a empty box shows up http://puu.sh/4x7PB.png :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it with something like that ?

```
$('.fancybox').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $.fancybox({
   'content': $(this).attr('href'),
   'type':'iframe'
});
```

Comment: No... Do you see the link above? Basically I want it so that when I click that link, it opens a fancy box (does not actually go to the link) and shows the data that is located in the link... It is kind of like a dynamic website. It grabs content from a different place and displays it on the screen...