# Bootstrap 3 Modal: `data-remote` loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My website uses `data-remote` on a bootstrap modal to load images. You can see the code in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199283/2537559) which I answered myself. The thing is that it might take a second or two to load the info so I would like to add a loading image (preferably the one used in fancybox). Im not 100% sure how to do this. It might be to add the image and when `modal-open` loads then remove the image. Im not 100% sure on how to do this and any help will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), you can use the event listeners:

`show.bs.modal` and `shown.bs.modal`

```
$(function()
{
    $(".modal").on("show.bs.modal",function()
    {
        // add loader indicator
    });
    $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal",function()
    {
        // remove loader indicator
    });
}
```

Your own answer to your other question does not have any javascript. So it's difficult to provide an answer that can be integrated into your current solution.

Comment: I will try the give code out. In my other answer, no js is required. Bootstrap.js loads everything that is required for modals. If your answer does work out, I will be sure to give you the rep.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is working fine! Unfortunately I can only award your reputation in 12 hours and I will do so then! Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem. Even without the bounty I would have seen and attempted to answer.

Answer (score 3):

A `loaded.bs.modal` event will be present in Bootstrap v3.1.0 (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10911); listening for this event is preferable to listening to `shown.bs.modal`.